Sisense import of data model is failing when use JDBC connectivity to BigQuery
We build couple of dashboards and data models in our QA environment and trying to move these to Prod. We follow the following steps

Export data models including security, hierarchies and formulas
Export dashboards
Import data models then at the end import dashboards
Finally change the database provider to link Prod BQ

The step 3 is failing and not able to import data models
Please see below error
enter image description here
I tried to import test cube

Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site help section useful when it comes to asking a good question. To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a minimal reproducible example. Here's a question checklist you might find useful...

This is the issue with sisense but I found a work around
I used sisense git integration and pushed the data models and dashboards to our QA branch and merged these to Prod. Finally, imported data models and dashboards to Prod. The API which creates these entities is working. This approach will avoid the JavaScript all together
